# Is it possible to put three separate SELECTs together in a single SQL query where two of the SELECTS grab data for the first SELECT?

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

If I worded the initial question poorly hopefully this description clears it up. I have a SQL query that is a SELECT like so

```
select tester as TESTNAME, testing as TESTNAMETWO, test as TESTNAMETHREE
from DATABASE.table master
inner join DATABASETWO.table2 notmaster
on master.column = notmaster.column2
where master.number = 55555
and notmaster.column3 in (~~~DATA I'M MISSING AND NEED~~~)
```

Now my issue is that I need to get a list of integers (The DATA IM MISSING at the bottom of the query) during this SQL query and I believe I'll need two SELECTS to do it in addition to the initial SELECT. I have two other tables I'd need to work with, first I'll need to use an id (The ID can be the 55555 in the initial query) to grab a value from the first table like so

```
select secondValue as identifier from THEDB.THETABLE foo
where foo.id = 55555
```

Then using that value we just got, I'll look for a match in the second table, then grab a value from the row it found a match on like so.

```
select valuesNeeded as listofvalues from THEOTHERDB.TABLE bar
where bar.value = identifier
```

That value we grabbed called listofvalues will be the list of integers I'll need in the first SELECT, so once that is grabbed, I can use that value in the initial SELECT during the IN part. Is there a way to do this in strictly SQL and in one query? I can make code changes, but just changing the SQL query itself is much easier for me currently. Thanks for any help/pointers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the WITH feature to create "temporary" tables that can be used later.

Something like this maybe?

```
WITH identifier AS (
  select secondValue as identifier 
  from THEDB.THETABLE foo
  where foo.id = 55555
), valuelist AS (
  select valuesNeeded as listofvalues 
  from THEOTHERDB.TABLE bar
  where bar.value in (SELECT identifier FROM identifier)
)
select tester as TESTNAME, testing as TESTNAMETWO, test as TESTNAMETHREE
from DATABASE.table master
inner join DATABASETWO.table2 notmaster on master.column = notmaster.column2
where master.number = 55555
  and notmaster.column3 in (SELECT listofvalues FROM valuelist)
```

You can also do sub queries -- functionally the same as above:

```
select tester as TESTNAME, testing as TESTNAMETWO, test as TESTNAMETHREE
from DATABASE.table master
inner join DATABASETWO.table2 notmaster on master.column = notmaster.column2
where master.number = 55555
  and notmaster.column3 in (
    select valuesNeeded as listofvalues 
    from THEOTHERDB.TABLE bar
    where bar.value in (
      select secondValue as identifier 
      from THEDB.THETABLE foo
      where foo.id = 55555
    )
  )
```

But the best way to this in SQL is with joins

```
select tester as TESTNAME, testing as TESTNAMETWO, test as TESTNAMETHREE
from DATABASE.table master
join DATABASETWO.table2 notmaster on master.column = notmaster.column2
join THEOTHERDB.TABLE bar on notmaster.column3 = bar.valuesNeeded
join THEDB.THETABLE foo on foo.id = 5555 AND bar.value = foo.secondValue
where master.number = 55555
```

Comment: I went with the sub-query route and it works great! Lead me to something else though, is there an alternative to "in" that we're using that can use a string of commas separated values? Data grabbed is a string like "1,2,3,4" and "in" seems to only use a list like so (1,2,3,4,5). Thanks, Hogan!

Comment: @Lenny if the string is consistent (ie always the same number of spaces before and after commas) you can do a sub-string search and then also check for start and end.  -- that is look for the substring ",2," or start with "2," and end with ",2" if you want to find if 2 is there.

Comment: @Lenny - note, the best way is to have the data sent as a table parameter

Comment: @Lenny you will be much better off if you normalize "TheOtherDB.Table" so that instead of having a single record with [ID, ListOfValues] = [55555,"1,2,3,4"], you have four records: [55555, 1], [55555, 2], [55555, 3], [55555, 4]. Then you will not have to jump through horrible hoops to split your string up into values that SQL can actually use.